# cyclic dependency in composite structure with template specialization

Tags: c++, template-specialization, composite, cyclic-dependency

Does anyone know a way to use template specialization with a custom class which is used in a composite structure?

To be specific, I'm writing a program to parse/validate an XML document where the XML data is stored in a custom composite tree structure which is constructed using my `class XMLNode` data structures as below.

Each XMLNode object stores child nodes in its `std::unordered_set<XMLNode> children` member and I want to use template specialization of the `std::hash` structure so that new nodes can be inserted using a specialized hashing function for XMLNode objects. This is what I have so far:

```
    #include <string>
    #include <unordered_map>
    #include <forward_list>
    #include <unordered_set>

    class XMLNode {

    private:

        std::string element_name;
        std::forward_list<std::string> content;
        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> attributes;
        **std::unordered_set<XMLNode> children;**

    public:

        // default constructor - sets member variables to empty containers and parent pointer to NULL.
        XMLNode() : element_name(), content(), attributes(), children() {};

        // copy constructor
        XMLNode(const XMLNode & node) : element_name(node.element_name), content(node.content), attributes(node.attributes), children(node.children) {};

        // destructor - members of the object are automatically emptied and freed when object passes out of scope.
        ~XMLNode() {};

        // copy assignment operator - deep copy
        XMLNode & operator = (const XMLNode & rhs)
        {
            element_name = rhs.element_name;
            content = rhs.content;
            attributes = rhs.attributes;
            children = rhs.children;
            return *this;
        };

        // compare two nodes are equal (have equal names and attributes)
        bool operator ==(const XMLNode & comparison_node) const
        {
            return (element_name == comparison_node.element_name && attributes == comparison_node.attributes);
        };

        const std::string & get_name() const
        {
            return element_name;
        };

    };

    namespace std
    {
        template<>
        **struct hash<XMLNode>**
        {
            size_t
                operator()(const XMLNode & obj) const
            {
                return hash<string>()(obj.get_name()); // implementation not finalised.
            }
        };
    }

    int main() 
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

However the compiler has a problem with this since the `XMLNode` class has a dependency on `std::hash<XMLNode` (because of `std::unordered_set<XMLNode> children`) and `std::hash<XMLNode` requires `class XMLNode` to be defined first.

To be specific I get the following error when compiled with VS 15.4.4: `E1449   explicit specialization of class "std::hash<XMLNode>" must precede its first use (at line 575 of "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\type_traits")`

However placing the `std::hash<XMLNode>` definition before the `XMLNode` definition and forward declaring the `XMLNode` class doesn't offer a solution either.

Does anyone have a design solution to this problem? Or is this just not feasible in C++? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your classes first, define second. Along these lines (not tested):

```
class XMLNode;

namespace std {
  template<>
  struct hash<XMLNode> {
    size_t operator()(const XMLNode & obj) const;
  };
}

class XMLNode {
  /* actual definition here */
};

size_t std::hash<XMLNode>::operator()(const XMLNode & obj) const {
  /* actual definition here */
}
```